# Calling a variable from a void method

Tags: methods, call, void

Hey this is a very simple question. Can I call a variable, in this case an array, from a void method? I have declared my arrays at the class level and initialized them in a void method. Not sure it I am doing this correctly but I am trying to call the array from another class. I am a beginner. Thank you for the help.

ex:

```
public class HeyThere{
    public double me[];

    public void yeahYou(int you){
        me = new me[69]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since your class level array `me` is scoped as `Public`, you will be able to access it from another class after you instantiate the `HeyThere` class.

Ex:

```
public class HeyThereCaller
{
..
....
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
    ...
    ....
    HeyThere heyThereInstance = new HeyThere();
    double[] meArray = heyThereInstance.me;
    }
}
```

Comment: ah thats what I thought but lately i seem to be breaking many obscure java rules thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here you **declarate** a public  variable (array)

```
public double me[ ];
```

and here you **instantiate** it in a method

```
me = new me[69]
```

Answer (score 1):

`HeyThere obj1;  double a = obj1.me[0];` This is going to give an error in Java though, because `me` is not instantiated

Comment: Don't forget to call `obj1.yeahYou();` prior to accessing array

Comment: like: HeyThere hi = new HeyThere() ; hi.yeahYou(int ya) ; hi.me[ ] right?

Comment: `HeyThere* hi = new HeyThere();` or `HeyThere hi;` . In the first case, members are accessed through `->`, in the second case through `.` . Just like structs

Comment: hmm i didnt know you can refer to a class that way.

Comment: struct is just a special case of class, with members public by default, and having no functions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certainly can! Because `me` is public, you can access it from outside of the class in which it is stored.
Also, you spoke of accessing it from a void method. The return type of a method has no effect on the data it can access; `void` only means that the method doesn't return a value when called.
If you want to study how variables can be accessed in Java, there is some useful info [on this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Comment: This is the first oracle page that has been useful to me. Thank you so damn much

Comment: You're welcome. The Java tutorials can occasionally clarify things.